# In Databricks Spark, how is SparkContext shared across different processes?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

In https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/jobs.html#use-the-shared-sparkcontext it says:

> Because Databricks initializes the SparkContext, programs that invoke
> new SparkContext() will fail. To get the SparkContext, use only the
> shared SparkContext created by Databricks:
>
> ```
> val goodSparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
> val goodSparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
> ```

In [SparkContext#getOrCreate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#getOrCreate--) it says:

> This function may be used to get or instantiate a SparkContext and
> register it as a singleton object. Because we can only have one active
> SparkContext per JVM, this is useful when applications may wish to
> share a SparkContext. This method allows not passing a SparkConf
> (useful if just retrieving).

In [SparkSession.Builder#getOrCreate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.Builder.html#getOrCreate--) it says:

> Gets an existing SparkSession or, if there is no existing one, creates
> a new one based on the options set in this builder. This method first
> checks whether there is a valid thread-local SparkSession, and if yes,
> return that one. It then checks whether there is a valid global
> default SparkSession, and if yes, return that one. If no valid global
> default SparkSession exists, the method creates a new SparkSession and
> assigns the newly created SparkSession as the global default.
>
> In case an existing SparkSession is returned, the non-static config
> options specified in this builder will be applied to the existing
> SparkSession.

So my understanding is that Databricks somehow creates a SparkContext in some process, probably a JVM, and then executes the submitted JAR in a different JVM process. Is this understanding correct?

If it is, then how does the SparkContext sharing mechanism work across multiple processes?

If not, then what actually happens and how does SparkContext get shared?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Databricks, SparkContext/SparkSession are created when cluster is starting, and then you submitted jar is executed in the same JVM where SparkContext/SparkSession was created. The recommendations about not stopping SparkContext especially important when you are submitting job to the interactive cluster (not recommended for multiple reasons).

When you're using Python or R, you get separate Python/R processes, but they will use the same SparkContext.

Comment: Thanks you. How does the Databricks JVM process share the SparkContext with the separate Python process? What is the mechanism used (is it written to a file or something?)

Comment: it's in-memory communication.

Comment: Can you expand a little more? Does the SparkContext get serialized in the Java process then sent to the Python process over RPC? Is it shared in off-heap memory? Thank you.